# How to resize std::string to remove all null terminator characters?

Tags: c++

I'm using a `std::string` to interface with a C-library that requires a `char*` and a length field:

```
std::string buffer(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
TheCLibraryFunction(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

However, the `size()` of the string is the actual size, not the size of the string containing actual valid non-null characters (i.e. the equivalent of `strlen()`). What is the best method of telling the `std::string` to reduce its size so that there's <s>only 1 ending null terminator character</s> no explicit null terminator characters? The best solution I can think of is something like:

```
buffer.resize(strlen(buffer.c_str()));
```

Or even:

```
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]{};
TheCLibraryFunction(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
std::string thevalue = buffer;
```

Hoping for some built-in / "modern C++" way of doing this.

### EDIT

I'd like to clarify the "ending null terminator" requirement I mentioned previously. I didn't mean that I want 1 null terminator explicitly in `std::string`'s buffer, I was more or less thinking of the string as it comes out of `basic_string::c_str()` which has 1 null terminator. However for the purposes of the `resize()`, I want it to represent the size of *actual* non-null characters. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why do you need to resize it? Does your C function get upset if you're passing it more than the length parameter indicates?

Comment: nothing wrong with `buffer.resize(strlen(buffer.c_str()));`

Comment: @void: If a C library takes a `char*`+size, then they almost always accept embedded NUL characters. That's *why* C APIs take string lengths. What you want to do is usually unnecessary.

Comment: @NicolBolas This particular C function is writing to the specified buffer I give it, not reading from it. I left that detail out, sorry about that. I won't know exactly how many characters are written until after the function returns.

Comment: Option 3, where you don't make a string until after the call, seems best to me

Comment: @void.pointer: Then why do you need to do this? `basic_string::size` will give you the size of the buffer that can be written to. You want to tell the C function how much space it has to write into the buffer. Why do you need to truncate your buffer? If the C function returns how many characters it has written, just `resize` it to that afterwards.

Comment: @NicolBolas Because the size of the string after the call is technically a lie. I want it to be the size of actual characters, not the maximum size. If I use this string in a stream later, it writes out all the null characters as well which I don't want. In a way I'm abusing the size property of a string before the C function call to treat the string as a buffer with a maximum size.

Comment: @void.pointer as Nicol said: "*If the C function returns how many characters it has written, just resize it to that afterwards*". Does the C function do that? `std::string buffer(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, '\0'); int size = TheCLibraryFunction(&buffer[0], buffer.size()); buffer.resize(size);` I would find it very odd if a function taking a `char*`+maxsize doesn't return the real size. If not, just use `strlen(c_str())` after the function exits: `std::string buffer(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, '\0'); TheCLibraryFunction(&buffer[0], buffer.size()); buffer.resize(strlen(buffer.c_str()));`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many ways to do this; but probably the one to me that seems to be most "C++" rather than C is:

```
str.erase(std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), '\0'), str.end());
```

i.e. Erase everything from the first null to the end.

Comment: [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) doesn't return an iterator.

Comment: What about `str.resize(str.find('\0'));`?

Comment: @O'Neil you're right - would mean we have to add str.begin() (which breaks if not found) to it; or use std::find as liliscent said

Comment: I'm not sure whether I misunderstood OP's question, but this solution is flawed. If the original buffer is not null-terminated, the iterator is out of boundary.

Comment: @O'Neil Yeah that ran though my mind as well. Perhaps `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE+1` on the initial size, and then the previous snippet I gave would be safe.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify a misunderstanding. When I said I only wanted 1 trailing null terminator, I was implying the one that `std::string` manages & expects. So from the outside perspective, I don't want any explicit null terminators. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @void.pointer but std:string doesn't expect or require any null terminator

Comment: @UKMonkey From the perspective of `c_str()` it does. Not concerned about the implementation too much. Not disagreeing with you, just stating that I miscommunicated what I intended to ask for.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes - it will - but I answered the question at the time.  It has since changed;  I've updated my answer to match.

Comment: @void.pointer yes; c_str() will ensure that it provides a null terminated string; but this is NOT included in the size() call unless you explcitly add it to the string.  ie `std::string derp("hello")` has a length of 5, not 6

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
buffer.erase(std::find(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), '\0'), buffer.end());
```

Consider [`std::basic_string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) has an overload:

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

A more succinct way:

```
buffer.erase(buffer.find('\0'));
```

A one-liner may not suffice, however, since you need to check whether the `'\0'` is actually present, and `string::find()` returns [`std::string::npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) (equivalent to [`std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)) if not found, so a better bet would be:

```
if (const auto pos = buffer.find('\0'); pos != std::string::npos)  
    buffer.erase(pos);
```

Comment: This will remove the last '\0', which op said they didn't want.

Comment: This is also missing `#include <algorithm>` to be able to use `std::find`

Answer (score 2):

You can use buffer.find('\0') instead of strlen(buffer.c_str())

Answer (score 2):

Using your

```
std::string buffer(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
TheCLibraryFunction(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

To remove 0-terminators, simplest is:
`buffer = buffer.c_str();`
(also possibly fastest? - didn't test)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has some answers, but I also want to contribute with my answer, although this solution works for all null terminators only at the end of the string.

```
void rtrim_null(std::string& str) {
    str.erase(std::find_if(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), [](int character) {
        return '\0' != character;
    }).base(), str.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Liner using [boost::trim_if](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/trim_if.html) if you want to trim multiple characters (I wanted to remove `\r`, `\n`, `\0` and `' '`) from the string:

```
int main()
{
    std::string str("abcd \0 \r\n \0", 12);
    std::cout << "Str: " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Length: " << str.length() << std::endl;

    boost::trim_if(str, boost::is_any_of(std::string("\r\n\0 ", 4)));

    std::cout << "Length: " << str.length() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Str: abcd

Length: 12
Length: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give you a very QUICK and EASY answer. Just do:

```
yourStringWithNullChars = yourStringWithNullChars.c_str();
```

then

```
yourStringWithNullChars.shrink_to_fit();
```

Done, no need to search and replace, no need for external libraries. Yes, it's tested, I use here on my program. ;)

Bye.